# How can I pass in an id and route to my controller with Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, axios

I want to know how to pass in an id and a route like below with a post?

//something/entry/recordcoworkers/startdate/13

or

//something/entry/recordcoworkers/13/startdate

Here is my controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/RecordCoworkers")]
public class RecordCoworkersController : Controller
{
 // POST: api/RecordCoworkers/StartDate
    [HttpPost("StartDate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostRecordCoworkerStartDateAsync([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] RecordCoworker recordCoworker)
    {
        if (!Auth.IsRequestAuthorized(_context, User.Identity.Name, "Mpid2_Entry_Write"))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var result = await RecordCoworkersContext.PostRecordCoworkerStartDateAsync(_context, id, recordCoworker);

        switch (result)
        {
            case HttpResult.NoContent:
                return Ok();
            case HttpResult.NotFound:
                return NotFound();
            default:
                return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the axios post call

```js
axios.post('/api/RecordCoworkers/StartDate/' + id, {
  id: coworkerId,
  startDate: value,
}).then(function(response) {
  // Show response
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Show error
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map to this route 
`/api/recordcoworkers/startdate/13` you need'll to add the id parameter in your HttpPost like this:

```
[HttpPost("StartDate/{id}")]
```

Or if you want to use `/api/recordcoworkers/13/startdate` then you'll need it reversed order obviously:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/StartDate")]
```

You can read more about routing in the official Microsoft docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-name